# Listing of checkout items by user in Git

Tags: git, git-checkout

Is there any way to get listing of all check out files in git repositories by user?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I recommend trying to make it clearer, perhaps adding an example of some sort of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Git doesn't really have  "checkouts". Do you mean files that have been committed locally but not pushed?

Comment: I need check out file listing by all users. Same as we were able to do with VSS.

Comment: @ZaranaVyas No, you can't. Not in Git or any almost any other modern source control system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is a DVCS (**d**istributed **v**ersion **c**ontroll **s**ystem). Each clone of a Git repository is a totally separate full repository on its own. You don't have to have any central repository and you cannot "lock" files for modification like you do with a checkout on VSS.

So the answer is "No", you cannot get such a list. You don't even know how many clones of a repository are out there. You can also make a clone of a clone and so on.

In Git you don't lock files for modification, but you modify them, commit them and before you push you rebase or merge them, bringing together changes done by others or on different branches with your changes, resolving any conflicts.

If you now ask about binary files, well Git like most VCS is not best suited to version binary files anyway, as they are targeted to and optimized for sourcecode.